# How to see the query logs of Mysql in Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I want to see the queries that are being executed in mysql server, I found the solutions but my log file is hidden, I've tried to change Windows properties but the file still hidden, what should I do?

I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bits and Mysql WorkBench with server 5.6

```
mysql> show variables like '%general%';

+------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name    | Value     |
+------------------+-----------+
| general_log      | ON        |
| general_log_file | DIEGO.log |
+------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to find where query log located:

```
mysql> show variables like '%general%';
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                                 |
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
| general_log      | OFF                                   |
| general_log_file | /path/to/log                        |
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

and to turn on query log:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log  = 'ON';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

and, re-run `show variables like '%general%'`, then'general_log' is ON.

Comment: sorry, I only use a Linux server. but MySQL says that `The C:\ProgramData directory is hidden by default. You must change your folder options to view the hidden file. Choose Organize, Folder and search options, Show hidden folders.`. this may help you.

Comment: You can change log path. `SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/path/to';`. set log path to you can see.

Comment: ok, but path and to, what is? I need to put only the command above and run?

Comment: yeah, `SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'C:\some_folder\log_filename'`. some_folder must exist before you run `SET ...` and, run mysql query. then you can see it query log file.

Comment: Thanks, I put a folder in `%systemroot%` but in Windows the command need to be like this, `SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'C:/some_folder/log_filename'`...thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found other way if someone is using MySqlWorkBench.

Open the MysqlWorkBench, open the server status page.

Click em option file, and click in the tab logging.

Click in general_log_file, and choose where this file is gonna be.

And you can see the log file.